# Adding task in full build definition using SBT 0.13's new task syntax to project?

Tags: scala, sbt

I implemented a simple task to copy some files from a project's target directory to some other directory:

```
  lazy val publishFiles = taskKey[Unit]("publishes the files")

  lazy val publishFilesTask = publishFiles <<= (projectID, target, streams) map { (id, targetDir, streams) =>
    val Sprint = "99"
    val DestBaseDir = "/some/folder"
    val DestDir = new File(s"$DestBaseDir/Sprint$Sprint/${id.name}")
    val log = streams.log
    val ScoverageReportDir = "scoverage-report"
    val CoberturaFileName = "cobertura.xml"

    if (DestDir.exists)
      log.error(s"Destination Directory $DestDir exists, exiting ...")
    else {
      log.info(s"Copying test coverage report to $DestDir ...")
      sbt.IO.createDirectory(DestDir)
      sbt.IO.copyDirectory(targetDir / ScoverageReportDir, DestDir / ScoverageReportDir, overwrite = false)
      sbt.IO.copyFile(targetDir / "coverage-report" / CoberturaFileName, DestDir / CoberturaFileName)
    }
  }
```

The task is added to the project's settings:

```
  lazy val settings = ... ++ publishFilesTask ++ ..
```

And it works.

Now I wanted to change the task to use the new task syntax (introduced in sbt 0.13.0):

```
  lazy val publishFilesTask = taskKey[Unit]("publishes the files")

  publishFilesTask := {
    val Sprint = "99"
    val DestBaseDir = "/some/folder"
    val DestDir = new File(s"$DestBaseDir/Sprint$Sprint/${projectID.value.name}")
    val log = streams.value.log
    val ScoverageReportDir = "scoverage-report"
    val CoberturaFileName = "cobertura.xml"

    if (DestDir.exists)
      log.error(s"Destination Directory $DestDir exists, exiting ...")
    else {
      log.info(s"Copying test coverage report to $DestDir ...")
      sbt.IO.createDirectory(DestDir)
      sbt.IO.copyDirectory(target.value / ScoverageReportDir, DestDir / ScoverageReportDir, overwrite = false)
      sbt.IO.copyFile(target.value / "coverage-report" / CoberturaFileName, DestDir / CoberturaFileName)
    }
  }
```

So far, so good. But I don't how to add this task to a project. If I do it like with the old version

```
  lazy val settings = ... ++ publishFilesTask ++ ..
```

I'm getting this error:

```
  [error]  found   : sbt.TaskKey[Unit]
  [error]  required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
```

I looked at the documentation but did not find a solution for this issue. I guess it should be pretty easy...
  Im using sbt 0.13.0 (upgrade to a newer version is not possible at the moment) and my build script is a .scala build definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote are two different cases, if you check actual types in the first case you'll see: `Def.Setting[Task[Unit]]` and in your second case: `TaskKey[Unit]`, that's where an error comes from. You've actually missed this part:

```
lazy val publishFilesTask = publishFiles
```

New 0.13 syntax change has changed from applicative way of defining settings to a macro based. To fix this just do like you wrote in your first version:

```
lazy val publishFiles = taskKey[Unit]("publishes the files")

lazy val publishFilesTask = publishFiles := { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks! I often get confused because in the documentation most of the time build.sbt is used whereas I use a full fledged scala build script :-)

Comment: @Christian Take a look at [this](http://www.manning.com/suereth2/) book by Josh Suereth, it would be much easier to understand how sbt works

Comment: I'd recommend a simpler `publishFiles := { ... }` for `lazy val publishFilesTask = publishFiles := { ... }`.

Comment: But that's what didn't work for me. Or am I understanding something wrong?